# custom wordpress theme: layout images not displaying

Tags: php, html, css, image, wordpress

I'm building a custom wordpress theme.So I have my Theme folder with the following files/folders:

```
header.php
index.php
footer.php
style.css
/images
 picture-1.jpg
```

My problem is that I can't display correctly images using **img TAG** either in index.php,header.php and footer.php:

```
[..]
<div class="module">
<h4>General info</h4>
<img src="images/picture-1.jpg"/>
[..]
```

[image]

Images are existing and are displaying correctly if referenced by style.css :

```
.banner{
  background-image:url(images/picture-1.jpg);
}
```

Do I miss something?

thanks
Luca

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because your files aren't in `/images` relative to the page you're viewing, they're in `wp-content/themes/[yourthemename]/images`.

You can get round this by setting a `base` URL to the root of your site in the head section of your site and linking images as shown above or by using something like this:

`<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/picture-1.jpg" alt="alt text" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/img-9.png"/>
```