# Custom wordpress theme, images not displaying?

Tags: php, html, css, image, gif

So I attempted to look for a solution: 
[custom wordpress theme: layout images not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924722/custom-wordpress-theme-layout-images-not-displaying)

It did not work for me.

[image]

My directory for my theme is

```
wp-content/themes/fearnothing/
```

and consist of these files

```
/css(folder) 
/js (folder)
/images (folder)
header.php
index.php
function.php
footer.php
style.css
hrtbrk.gif
hrtbrk.png
```

css folder contains

```
fearnothing.css
```

js folder is empty

```
fearnothing.js
```

My header.php has the following code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>example title</title>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

    <body>

<img class ="nightsky" src="wp-content/themes/fearnothing/hrtbrk.png" alt ="3">
```

functions.php

```
<?php 
    function fearnothing_script_enqueue(){
        wp_enqueue_style('customstyle',  get_template_directory_uri().'/css/fearnothing.css',array(), '1.1.2', 'all');


    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fearnothing_script_enqueue');
```

fearnothing.css

```
html,body{
        background: black;
        color: #8c0707;
        font-family: Courier,Courier New,Lucida Sans Typewriter,Lucida Typewriter,monospace;
        font-size: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nightsky{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
        }
```

I'm trying to add the gif but it did not work. so I tried an image instead. I tested my code offline with html and it works fine?

**EDIT** 
I added a images folder to my theme where the theme would be located.

Comment: The markup in your header.php is wrong. Change the image tag to:
`<img class ="nightsky" src="wp-content/themes/fearnothing/hrtbrk.png" alt="">`

Comment: Also in your llst of files there is no "hrtbrk.png"

Comment: Ahh, should correct that. They are there I just had a typo here. I did the changes you suggested but it did not work :/

Comment: Did you alrady tried to open the image file directly? yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/fearnothing/hrtbrk.png

Comment: it just takes me to my wesbite.

Comment: You really should be using get_stylesheet_directory_uri() as explained in the WordPress Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Comment: @peter-cs This ("t just takes me to my website") is the problem. It's not related to wordpress or your HTML. Your server configurations seems to be wrong. If you try to open an image and get redirected to the website the image wasn't found or the server do not allow to access this file.

This would also explain why it's working when using the wordpress media upload, as you have explained. This is another directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a method that works which is not really how I wanted it to work.

I needed to upload the image directly through wordpress media.

Which is stored in `/wp-content/uploads`
I wanted the images to be inside the themes folder `wp-content/themes/fearnothing/images`

but for some odd reason the files are being corrupted. (hence the broken image file)

After uploading directly to the uploads folder I was able to use the tag I had originally.

```
<img  class ="nightsky" src="https://mywesbiteurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/hrtbrk.png" alt="" >
```

Answer (score 0):

add Home URL above wp-content

```
<img class ="nightsky" src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/fearnothing/hrtbrk.png" alt ="3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` function

```
<img class="nightsky" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/hrtbrk.png" alt="">
```

Reference [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/)

Comment: still doesn't display.

Comment: try using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this below options.

```
<img class ="nightsky" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/fearnothing/hrtbrk.png" alt ="3">

OR 

<img class ="nightsky" src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/fearnothing/hrtbrk.png" alt ="3">
```

Comment: it keeps giving me a broken file img.

Comment: Please check the file name one more time

Comment: please check image name If any capital letter & check image extension like (.png. jpg,.jpeg,.gif)

Comment: As a wordpress folder format please check it's theme folder image OR upload folder image?

Comment: the image and gif is the main theme folder along with the other files `wp-content/themes/fearnothing/`

Comment: Please open the image url in new browser tab
Ex: http://xxxxxx.com/content/themes/fearnothing/hrtbrk.png

If u able to see the image?

Comment: yeah, I don't see the image, does that mean the file is corrupt? Note; I added a image folder into my theme now as I've learned that is the proper way to do it. but still image doesn't show .

Comment: Please change the image name and check the image URL in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `get_template_directory()` function

`<img class="nightsky" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/hrtbrk.png" alt="">`